# Wildcard substitutions with Lua Font Handlers

Tags: luatex, substitution

Using LuaLateX `fonts.handlers.otf.addfeature`, is it possible to make a `substitution` with a wildcard search? For example, a substitution that would substitute any Cyrillic unicode character with a '.'?  In theory,  I can go and type every character in the various Cyrillic scripts plus accents, but this seems tedious when I know which unicode blocks contain them.